Submission History of student is mismatched
I tried to fetch the details of a student for a particular assignment in Google Classroom using the following API: /v1/courses/{courseId}/courseWork/{courseWorkId}/studentSubmissions.
From this API, I received the following submission history:
​
`"submissionHistory": [
{
"stateHistory": {
"state": "CREATED",
"stateTimestamp": "2024-10-17T04:03:48.182Z",
"actorUserId": "{student}"
}
},
{
"gradeHistory": {
"pointsEarned": 6,
"maxPoints": 10,
"gradeTimestamp": "2024-10-18T00:06:29.062Z",
"actorUserId": "{teacher}",
"gradeChangeType": "DRAFT_GRADE_POINTS_EARNED_CHANGE"
}
},
{
"stateHistory": {
"state": "RETURNED",
"stateTimestamp": "2024-10-18T00:06:49.796Z",
"actorUserId": "{teacher}"
}
},
{
"gradeHistory": {
"pointsEarned": 6,
"maxPoints": 10,
"gradeTimestamp": "2024-10-18T00:06:49.796Z",
"actorUserId": "{teacher}",
"gradeChangeType": "ASSIGNED_GRADE_POINTS_EARNED_CHANGE"
}
}
]`

​​
​​Based on above submission history, is it possible for grade points to be assigned immediately after the creation of an assignment, even if it hasn’t been turned in? Additionally, if an assignment is returned, is it possible to change the assigned grade points? If all these scenarios are indeed possible, in what specific situations might they occur?

Please provide a minimal reproducible example and your expected output by editing the question above.
